# .NET Core .csproj missing file path of .cs files in vs studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, csproj

where are files path location in .NET Core .csproj file? I edit project and open it and still not a single cs class file path.

This is one of the project example. This project have more than 1000 cs files in advance tree in Solution Explorer.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <!--<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>-->
    <RootNamespace>Microsoft.Web.Api.R1.BusinessLogic</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Microsoft.Web.Api.R1.BusinessLogic</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <Folder Include="GraphQL\Microsoft\Microsoft\R1\" />
    <Folder Include="MicrosoftHandlers\R1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Containers" Version="0.25.0" />       
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AccessTokenValidation" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Microsoft.Web.Api.R1\Microsoft.Web.Api.R1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: The files can be placed wherever you like. If you open the csproj file in a text editor (e.g. notepad) you can see entries for all the files which are associated with the project, and where they are supposed to be located (the paths are usually expressed relative to the location of the csproj file).

Comment: I did it and still I not see any file path (.cs) files. Only references, packages and that is all. Also did not find any .json file with file path.

Comment: Well then, maybe the project doesn't actually contain any files. It's possible. There is actually no requirement for the project to contain .cs files (or any other types of files). Did you have a particular expectation of what files should be there?

Comment: The project have solution also. In the project have more then 100 .cs files (classes). I am 100% sure. the project is .net core API kind of type. This is the most modern project I have ever saw. It is own and develop by the Microsoft. It seems we use some very modern kind of Visual Studio and project ;) I am old school developer and this confuses me ;)

Really, no body saw this new Visual Studio/project .net core type?

Comment: Who knows? You didn't share the contents of the csproj file, or the folder structure etc. Are the files physically there in the folder, but just not showing the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio? It's not really clear, from your very brief description. Also, if it's some Microsoft thing, can we see it on GitHub or somewhere? They share most of their code examples online.

Comment: P.S. did you read the tag description for "core" before you added it to your question? It's unrelated to your problem. All tags have descriptions, please read them and don't guess. I've added some more relevant tags. Now more people with relevant knowledge might see your question :-)

Comment: First off, thanks for tag edits. Second, I can not share anything due to Microsoft security policy. I will try to explain with more details. 

I am old school developer and work in Microsoft from a week ago. We work with very new Visual Studio which I have never saw before. Anywhere!!!

Comment: As I understate , it is a project .Net Core 3. The solution in fact have 20 any more projects. Each project have many classes (.cs) files. I can add new class or delete class. The project file never ever edit anything. My first thing was "this new studio have bug". Then when I unload project and open it like a simple text file(notepad) I saw only references, nuget packages and I did not saw a single .cs file path. I check many project and all of them not have files location.

This is so strange

Comment: If you don't understand .NET Core maybe you should do some training. If you're working for Microsoft, surely they are providing training on their own technologies?? It is a little bit different to .NET Framework in certain ways. I personally though am not familiar with whether this specific thing you talk about would be a difference, I haven't used .NET Core much just yet. Maybe a good idea would be to try and create a new .NET Core project of your own using visual studio 2019, and see if you get the same situation or not. Then maybe you'll know if it's you, or the project, or a real bug.

Comment: I share example, one of the simple Microsoft project in regards of Azure feature.

Comment: @ADyson My work is related with since and mathematics. Sure, you a right. Still this is not a topic at the moment. I just wanted to ask. Is there anybody use this kind of project type?

Comment: the new [SDK format implicitly adds all items](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/csproj.md#default-compilation-includes-in-net-core-projects), to keep the csproj simple and small. You have to manually exclude unwanted items.

Comment: @magicandre1981  This is the correct answer as I thing before. Thank you very much mister. Just post your answer and I will give you positive feedback.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can [accept the reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 7):

This is [expected with the new SDK based csproj format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#default-includes-and-excludes):

> Unlike non-SDK .NET Framework projects, **you don't need to specify
> these items in your project file**, because the defaults cover most
> common use cases. **This behavior makes the project file smaller and
> easier to understand and edit by hand, if needed.**

This change makes the csproj files smaller and easier to read.

If you have a file that you want to exclude you can do this in the UI or edit the csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Foo\Bar.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```